# ICU Transliterator doesn't work without -O2 flag with g++

Tags: g++, icu

I have been having problems with ICU's rule-based Transliterator which turned out to be caused by a missing `-O2` flag on debug builds using g++ 4.7.1. It was working fine when I did a release build (which had `-O2`), but when I built my project without that flag for debugging, the `Transliterator` object would never be created properly.

```
Transliterator* t = Transliterator::createFromRules(id, rules, UTRANS_FORWARD, parseError, status);
```

Without optimisation, `t` is assigned a null pointer and `status` is set to 32767, which translates to `BOGUS UErrorCode` when run through ICU's `u_errorName()`.

The first thing I tried was to remove the `-g` debug flag from my build, but that made no difference to what `createFromRules()` returned. Only when I added `-O2` did it create the `Transliterator` object.

Testing indicates that `-O1`, `-O2` and `-O3` all work as expected, and only `-O0` causes this to happen.

Can someone explain why this should be the case?

Comment: It looks like *the* perfect situation for using a debugger.

Comment: @n.m. Well, I guess I could rebuild ICU with debugging symbols...

Comment: @n.m. usually it's the other way - debug mode 'solves' it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have different results with/without debugging. Can you create a small test case including rules, give the ICU version and OS/platform, and file a ticket? 4.7.1 was released 2 months ago. Could be a compiler bug (ICU has a **long** history of finding those!!) or latent bug. You can link the bug to this question and vice versa.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen does it happen with all rules or just one set?

Comment: @StevenRLoomis I've only tried it with a single rule set. I have, however, checked the UnicodeString to ensure that its contents were correct before the function call. I should add that `parseError` has the line and column numbers set to something out of range for my rule set, but both are non-negative.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen can you include the rule set here? Otherwise it's difficult to analyze. Or, perhaps try a simple rule such as `A>B;`

Comment: @StevenRLoomis Even a trivial rule like `v > w;` fails with `-O0` but works with `-O2`.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen I am sorry if I am not being clear.  You have not given enough information still:  You have not indicated which platform you are on, which processor architecture, nor which version of ICU. I was asking for these things in my first answer.  And in any event, I recommend filing a bug report at http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac  - this is *not* the appropriate forum for filing bugs.

Comment: @StevenRLoomis I've been waiting to come up with a minimal program which reproduces the issue before submitting a bug report - something I've not yet been able to do. I'd like to be reasonably certain it is an ICU issue before doing so. From your later comments, I understood that you were requesting some further information here, notably about the rule sets involved.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen I'll followup there on the ticket.

Comment: @SigueSigueBen finally making some progress here. I commented on your ticket, looks like clang and/or GCC 4.7 may have found some a real bug. See if the patch I pasted into  http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/9525#comment:1 makes a difference?